# Use javascript variables as arguments in class method in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, variables

How can I use use javascript variables in C# code?

or

How can I assign C# variable value in javascript (from another javascript variable) in cshtml

Answer (score 0):

Do you realize that your web pages are first processed **on the server** by IIS, using C#, and then transferred to **the client**, where JavaScript is executed?

This means that you technically can use your C# variables in your JavaScript code by something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var productID = @Model.ProductID;
</script>
```

but not vice versa.

Maybe you should consider using AJAX to make the additional requests to the server without the need to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden variables. values can be assigned from js --> c# and vice versa.
Or you can create properties in c# and access/assign values to them from js.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield%28v=VS.90%29.aspx